# Hotcakes 1.10 - Password has been reset email is begin sent when using checkout as a guest

Tags: e-commerce

We are having an issue on a website. When a customer checkouts as a guest, the system sends an email with a random generated password to the user.

After trying to follow the guide at https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/209539786-Replacing-the-User-Account-Creation-Workflow-Task to customize the behavior so no emails are sent, we realized that the demo code does not compile. Some functions seem to be missing (probably breaking changes in earlier versions). The code that does not work is inside LoginNewUser().

```
private static void LoginNewUser(OrderTaskContext context, CustomerAccount n)
{
  string errorMessage = string.Empty;
  string userId = string.Empty;
  UserAccount userAcc = null;
  Hotcakes.Commerce.Dnn.DnnAccountService.LoginDnnUser(n.Username, n.Password, context.HccApp.CurrentRequestContext.RoutingContext.HttpContext, out errorMessage, out userAcc);
}
```

The errors here are :

- UserAccount class is not defined.
- LoginDnnUser method is not defined.

Does anybody know how to fix these two errors? After that, the custom workflow will allow me not to send emails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your LoginNewUser method to be like the example below:

```
private static void LoginNewUser(OrderTaskContext context, CustomerAccount n)
{
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
    string userId = string.Empty;

    context.HccApp.MembershipServices.LoginUser(n.Username, n.Password, out errorMessage, out userId);
}
```